# openscene graph geode color array

Tags: opengl, graphics, openscenegraph

After loading a image with openscenegraph I am trying to access the color array for the current geode. However, all I have been able to do is change the contents of the color array.Any advice on how to access a color array of a node in openscenegraph would be great.

Comment: Define *access*. If you can change the colors inside the array, then you're accesing the array already. Also, some code would help to understand you better.

Answer (score -1):

A Geode contains Drawables, which could be geometric things made of polygons, or could be something else.

http://trac.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00222.html

You want the drawables that are of class Geometry

http://trac.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00321.html

and then you can getColorArray on them.

This:

> However, all I have been able to do is change the contents of the color array. Any advice on how to access a color array of a node in openscenegraph would be great.

is unclear. What color array were you able to change and how were you able to access it if you don't know how to access a color array.

Some specifics and example code you're using would also help.

Comment: Half of this answer belongs in a comment on the question.